# QT + Android unable to debug Error: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function

Tags: android, qt, qt5

Totally running out of ideas, the situation is depicted along with lots of logs over here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/121687/breakpoints-not-hit-on-android/5

The only reasonable error message within app log seems to be it:"Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function."

Sysroot set seems like tried many things already.

Here https://www.fayewilliams.com/2013/01/31/gdb-unable-to-find-dynamic-linker-breakpoint-function/

I've found information related to the error, still how do I proceed from here if the sysroot path is set corectly

***Update**: I've reinstalled QT, Android SDK, QT Creator, still the same. I've uninstalled entire QT in hopes of removing all the seetings, the settings (ex. for kits survived).Spent day and a half on that one. I get an error for a new Hello World project. It's the same error.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I described what worked for me in hopes that nobody else ever needs to go through all the stuff I went through before coming up with a solution. It wasted almost 2 of my work days. The first included reinstallation of everything to no avail. The second => spawning an entirely new Windows 10 VM and installing everything (100GB QT stuff and so on).

Guess what?  on a new windows installation everything worked out-of the box.

So I took my time comparing all of the settings.

On the faulty system the CMake Tool was set to an external one (yes I updated CMake also) on the working system CMake is set to CMake(qt) AND what I THINK made the real difference is the CMake generator settings. On the working system it is set to Generator: Ninja , extra generator:none.

**So to sum up how I made it work:**
In your kit's setttings:

- change CMake to CMake(qt)
- Generator: Ninja , extra generator:none.
  [image]
- CLEAR the sysroot field (yes do it) and within the debugger settins also leave BOTH of the textual fields EMPTY
  [image]

**Bottom line?** I DID NOT play around with these settings myself. EVER. And nobody else has access to this development machine. I have no idea what caused this.

Also I do not know why setting the sysroot field actually prevents this from working. If I set sysroot OR change generator from Ninja to something else, the error is back.

One more thing to fellow developers. Note that now there's a Start Debugging => Debug Without Deployment which allows to start debugging in matters of seconds in the new QT Creator.Side note: the error that there was no response from GDB for 20 seconds remains.